# Ansible: ec2 aws plugin - How to associate ec2 host to ansible group based on aws_profile?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm sure there must be a simple answer, **but**, when I use the `aws_ec2` plugin to create a dynamic inventory for Ansible, I use the following setup so that I can pass the profile in to the inventory (to get the correct credentials):

```yaml
plugin: aws_ec2
aws_profile: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_PROFILE') | default('dev-profile', true) }}"
regions:
  - us-east-1
```

Now, I want all of these hosts to be associated with a group which has the name of the AWS_PROFILE passed in.  How do I do this?

I tried:

```yaml
groups:
    dev_group: aws_profile == 'dev-profile'
    test_group: aws_profile == 'test-profile'
```

but was unsuccessful (no groups were created).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you sets a value to the parameter `aws_profile` in your inventory does not makes it available in a variable.

So what you have to do is to reuse the same lookup in your `groups` conditions:

```yaml
groups:
  dev_group: lookup('env', 'AWS_PROFILE') | default('dev-profile', true) == 'dev-profile'
  test_group: lookup('env', 'AWS_PROFILE') | default('dev-profile', true) == 'test-profile'
```

Comment: Looks great, but is there any way to reuse the lookup expression (rather than including it three times)?

Comment: Doesn't really look like. Your requirement is kind of odd, though, what is most common Is to have information for the EC2 host (labels or any other type of built in info), then use [`keyed_groups`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html#parameter-keyed_groups).